# How to convert text to number a type of encryption in php

Tags: php, encryption

I want to convert a text to number using any two way encryption function in PHP ..
So that if I'm converting a text or string into a random encrypted number , again I can convert back it to string ...
Please help me..
I have also used crc32 function but that is one way hashing ...so  I want a two way hashing function..
Please help me

Comment: Why do you want this?  Why can't you use a reputable encryption algorithm like AES?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I want to try this...this is not for any commercial project and all..but i wanna learn how to do this

Comment: You'll need to be more clear then - I don't really understand what you want to do.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark suppose there is string... $str = "hello world"; now I want to convert it to any random number like... 53891999 any thing...I have do this with the help.of crc32 but...now I can't able to convert that random number back to the original text...so I wanted to make this type of hashing function which convert text to number and then number to text...it will be same type of encryption and decryption..

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark please help me sir

Comment: CRC32 is an error checking code, it has nothing to do with encryption or hashing...  It, by definition, cannot be "reversed" because there is nothing to reverse it to.  Rather than explaining **what** you want to do, can you tell me **why** you want to do it so I can help you find what you need?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark is it possible to encrypt user data and store it to any database where encryption algorithm differs user to user..something like with a unique key ...in php?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark also...like md5 is like default encryption program... encryption algorithm is same for all...so I don't wanna use that... .

Comment: MD5 is, again, **not** an encryption algorithm.  If this is for passwords, you should not be encrypting, you should be using a proper password hash like bcrypt.  Please see the PHP function [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) - it is designed for precisely this.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark so..how can I use aes in php...please demonstrate a example please sir..

Comment: No, don't use AES for passwords.  AES provides encryption **and** decryption.  Passwords should never be able to be decrypted - we hash them with algorithms designed for password hashing.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I'm not using for this for passwords...I want to use this for simple user data for example : messages

Comment: Then yes, AES is an appropriate algorithm to use here.  Please see [this repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) for a collection of secure symmetric encryption examples.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark sir can you please demonstrate a example for using this aes encryption

Comment: I just linked an example above.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems you does not know what encryption is. To make its algorithm you have to know first what it is

I recommend to learn some basic cyphers to make your own, an easy one is ADFGVX; search the internet and try to understand how it works.

Your question is indeed a first step in encryption, but it is totally up to you that how you convert the input text to number, you can call A=1, B=2, C=4 or A=65, B=66 which are ASCI equals of alphabets or even you can make your own list to change characters to numbers

Second step is to shuffle the numbers in such a way that only you can unshuffled them but without knowing how to do that others should not be able to do that or may find it very difficult to do that.

Then there is a concept of key or password. Some cyphers encrypt the input using a key and the decryption can only be done using that key, if one doesn’t know the key it would be very difficult or impossible to decrypt it.

Internationally there are many cyphers some of them are considered week which means that without knowing the key they can be decrypted easily and some are strong which means decryption is very difficult, in answers to you question you have read the name AES, this is a names a standard cypher. You can find built-in functions for many cyphers in different programming languages.

This is just an introduction; there are many topics that can be discussed but it is up to you how much you want to learn

Now for the answer to your question

You can start building your cypher using the below code.

```
    $encrypted_text = encrypt("abcd");
    $decrypted_text = decrypt($encrypted_text);
    var_dump($decrypted_text);

    function encrypt($input_str){

        $output_str = "";
        $charachters = str_split($input_str);

        for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($charachters) ; $i++){

            $output_str .= str_pad(ord($charachters[$i]), 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
        return $output_str;
    }

    function decrypt($input_str){

        $output_str = "";
        $charachters = str_split($input_str,3);

        for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($charachters) ; $i++){

            $output_str .= chr($charachters[$i]);
        }
        return $output_str;
    }
```

Comment: MD5 is not a "cipher".  It is a hashing algorithm and is irrelevant to encryption.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to get a number equivalent to a ski code

```
    <?php
$A=ord("H"); 
echo($A);   
?>
```

result = 72

Comment: Now how to convert this number back to string

Comment: you can use this : "echo chr(72);"

Comment: `ord` and `chr` have no support for UTF-8 at all.  Additionally, this isn't secure in the slightest.